# How to derive an inequality for the solution of a differential equation based on a differential inequality?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Suppose that the following differential inequality holds:

$$ \dot{y}(t) \leq -c\cdot y(t) + \lambda \ \ (1)$$

with $c,\lambda > 0 $ positive constants. Now let $\rho = \lambda /c > 0$, I'm wondering how the following is concluded from equation (1):

$$ y(t) \leq \rho + y(0)\cdot e^{-c\cdot t} - \rho\cdot e^{-c\cdot t} \ \ (2)$$

I know that the differential equation $\dot{y}(t) = -c\cdot y(t) + \lambda$ has the solution $y(t) = y(0)\cdot e^{-c\cdot t} + \rho$ but I can't figure out why (2) holds.
Note that $y(t)$ is a positive definite function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(1)&\iff \dot{y}(t) + c\cdot y(t)\leq  \lambda \\
&\iff e^{ct}\left(\dot{y}(t) + c\cdot y(t) \right) \le  \lambda e^{ct} \\
&\iff (e^{ct}y(t))' \le  \lambda e^{ct} \\
&\iff e^{ct}y(t) - y(0) \le \lambda \int_0^t  e^{cs}ds \\
\end{align}$$
And you can deduce easily $(2)$.